# How can I make URL routing for subfolders in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to the Asp.net MVC4 , I need to define rout for folder structure mention below,

```
Views/Home                  (Desired URL: /Home)
Views/Admin/CorePages/City  (Desired URL: /Admin/CorePages/City)
```

for 'Home' URL routing working perfect but for sub-folder such as 'Admin/CorePages/City' it is not routing as per URL,How do I create route?

Note: My Controller are place in same manner in controller folder.

Comment: Routing is not done per-view, it is done per controller. Please read about basics of MVC routing, you should find the answer quite easily

Comment: Thank you for your comment, let me read more basics of MVC routing.